# POP3 to IMAP Server

Tags: email-client, imap, email-server, pop3

I have a GoDaddy hosting account with a few POP3 e-mail accounts. (This is for personal use.) I want to transition to IMAP - to keep all devices synced. However there is an extra charge for that which I would like to avoid.

So my plan is to setup a server on my network that automatically downloads from the POP3 accounts, stores the e-mails locally, and makes them available via IMAP. I have a DynDns account, so I shouldn't need a static IP.

Is there existing software to do this?

Comment: What OS do you plan to run this on? As the server itself isn't the point here, what you need is something like [Fetchmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetchmail), which retrieves mails from POP3 and "feeds" them to your IMAP server. To recommend a matching tool (Fetchmail runs on *nix), we need to know your OS requirements and, maybe, the budget available (or whether the software must come free of charge). Btw: As that script would most likely run on your server, static/dynamic IP is not an issue at all :)

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, forgot to mention OS: I was thinking of using a dedicated RPi running Raspbian. Also, I have a Windows 7 box I can use. I will take a look at fetchmail. Thanks.

Comment: On a Pi, fetchmail should be the perfect candidate. You're most likely running on Raspian there, so it should even be in the repos, and a simple `apt-get install fetchmail` should suffice for installation. As for the mail server, I'd then recommend dovecot; I'm running that on my BananaPi and am pretty much pleased: dovecot+postfix+amavis (and some additions), handle the load for 4 domains here, including primary MX. If that sounds interesting for you, let me know and I check my notes at home for a fitting answer; but I'd suggest splitting that for a separate question then (1xfetchmail,1ximap)